# How to Advance time by atleast 45 minutes in Kotlin Espresso Test

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso

I have a scenario, wherein if the user stays idle on the screen for 45 minutes, I will have to transfer the user to home screen.

In my Espresso test, I want to recreate the scenario, and i would not want to wait for 30 minutes for that to happen.

Is there a way we can advance time in Espresso?

I have checked idlingresource and waitingforview etc, but none of  them seemed right to me. Can anyone guide me on how to advance time in espresso?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about manipulating the system clock for a test, but instead of hardcoding a 45-minute wait, you might want to handle the time limit with dependency injection - either by setting a `timeout` property, or passing in a `Clock` object that the code refers to, instead of accessing the system clock directly.

That way your test can either configure it with a more useful timeout setting, or the `Activity` (or whatever) can poll a `Clock` that you're able to manipulate from the test. (Having a configurable timeout would allow you to do things like set it as a user option too, maybe change the value in power-saving mode, etc)